# White Screen when switching between Swing frames under Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing

I'm porting a Java Swing application from Windows to Linux.
On Linux - when the application switches between JFrames, a blink of white screen appears for a split of a second.
This doesn't happen with the same application on Windows.
I believe that the white screen appears while the new frame is repainted.
Any idea how to fix it?

Here's the code that switches between frames (pages):

```
public void goToPage(int page) {
    screens[page].bringToFront(true);
    if (page != currentFrame) {
        screens[page].setVisibility(true);
        screens[currentFrame].setVisibility(false);
        currentFrame = page;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a CardLayout instead.

Comment: 1. Moving to CardLayout is a big change. It's almost re-writing the entire application, as the screens are JFrames and CardLayout works with JPanels.